# Process A leave MemoryMapFile available for Process B

Tags: windows, ipc, memory-mapped-files

Been Googling, but can't find an answer to this. Have not used `MemoryMappedFile` before. Have just been reading about them with a view to implementing basic IPC. Before I invest time prototyping can anyone tell me whether the following logic will work?

I had in mind to use a non-persisted memory-mapped file, so that it is automatically cleaned up after use.

1. Process A opens `MemoryMappedFile` and writes to it.
2. Process A launches process B
3. **Process A quits**
4. Process B performs `OpenExisting` on `MemoryMappedFile` created by process A
5. Process B reads data from `MemoryMappedFile` and does processing...

Process A & B will both know the name of the file.

Will the file created by Process A remain until process B has disposed of it?

What are the mechanics, should process A not `Dispose` the file and let Process B do that?

If this logic will not work then I was considering that Process A wait for Process B to complete, but this is not ideal.

Thanks for any shedding of light ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work, except process B needs to open a handle to the memory mapped file before process A closes its handle. The reason is that the memory mapped file is destroyed when the last handle is closed.

(I assume we're talking Windows here.)

---

Edit: I got interested in this and did a bit more reading…

Probably the most correct and robust way to do this would be for process B to inherit a handle to to the memory mapping. Some links:

- [Handle Inheritance in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Programmatically controlling which handles are inherited by new processes in Win32](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/16/10248328.aspx)
- [How do I pass a lot of data to a process when it starts up?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/11/56043.aspx)

I think this last link provides you with a model answer by one of the most knowledgeable Windows programmers in the world. Do read the comments below the article as well.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I thought that might be the case. Probably safer that I use a persisted file and let process B do the clean-up.

Comment: Yes, if you don't mind the possibility of the file being left around if something fails. But really it shouldn't be too hard to implement some kind of interlock so process A doesn't close its handle until process B has opened its handle. Process B could set an event.

Comment: Another alternative might be for Process A to duplicate a handle and have process B inherit this duplicated handle. I haven't tried this but it should work. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - yes, that would be the proper way to do it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for all your help. I will be sure to give them a read. Did a bit of further reading today about anonymous pipes, passing the handle to the child process via the command line parameters. It will not be a huge amount of data and the child process will not need to pass anything back to the parent, so this seems like it could also fit the bill. Waters successfully muddied ;)

Comment: If it really is a small amount of data then passing it on the command line is easiest.

Comment: If you use a pipe for IPC then you need to watch out for creating a deadlock. Probably won't affect you if the comms is unidirectional, but I don't think it is necessarily the simplest way to do things.